# JSF change value in Composite Attribute

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I want change value according to firstoption and secondoption 
if firstoption = go and second = true I want MASK in value "A"
if firstoption = stop and second = true MASK = "B"
etc

It's possible using without managebean set inputbox and can change value in inputbox?

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" />
    <composite:attribute name="firstoption"  type="java.lang.String"/>
    <composite:attribute name="secondoption"  d type="java.lang.Boolean" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="first" value="#{cc.attrs.firstoption}" >
        <p:ajax update="action"/>
        <f:selectItem  itemValue="GO" />
        <f:selectItem  itemValue="STOP"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="second" value="#{cc.attrs.secondoption}" >
        <p:ajax update="action"/>
        <f:selectItem  itemValue="#{true}" />
        <f:selectItem  itemValue="#{false}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

     <p:inputText id="action" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
     <h:panelGrid>
</composite:implementation>
```

Maybe something like this with button ?

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{cc.attrs.value}" value="A" />
```

but can't use that to inputtext/selectonemenu

Comment: What do you mean by `MASK in value "A"` or `MASK = "B"` ?

Comment: If i choose go and true, in inputtext must show value "A" (value attribue "name" is "A") and i can edit this value in inputtext